# All of my POST request data is correct, and it (seemingly) follows all of BAND's documentation, am I just making a dumb mistake?

Tags: python, json, post, httprequest

I'm using the following code to make a HTTP POST request to BAND's api (https://developers.band.us/develop/guide/api)

```
import requests

api_url = "https://openapi.band.us/v2.2/band/post/create"
access_token = "Correct Access Token"

post_data = {
    "access_token": "Correct Access Token",
    "band_key": "Correct Band Key",
    "content": "Testing"
}

headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}

try:
    response = requests.post(api_url, json=post_data, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 201:
        print("Post successfully created!")
        print(response.json())
    else:
        print(f"Failed to create a post. Status code: {response.status_code}")
        print(response.text)

except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
```

I've tried changing the parameters inside of `requests.post` many times, but I keep getting this error:

```
Failed to create a post. Status code: 400
{"result_data":{"message":"invalid parameter : org.apache.catalina.util.ParameterMap@2ada5b7e[locked=true,threshold=12,loadFactor=0.75]"},"result_code":3000}
```

Am I just forgetting something or what? I'm just making this for fun and to learn about HTTP requests, so I'm not very experienced.